# Hyperledger fabric facing difficult setting up intermediate CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, x509certificate2

I am trying to create intermediate CA for my project, I have one root CA and one intermediate CA with Intermediate CA config file as shown below. I am facing issue to create keypairs/MSP and tls cert for intermediate CA & unable to pass the config file to intermediate CA. Steps I followed

1. Running the Root CA container with bootstrapping admin.
2. Enrol the admin which generate the MSP for CA admin for org1

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054 --caname ca-org1 --tls.certfiles ${PWD}/organizations/fabric-ca/org1/tls-cert.pem
```

3. Register the Intermediate CA to root CA using below command

```
fabric-ca-client register --caname ca-org1 --id.name ica --id.attrs '"hf.Registrar.Roles=user,peer",hf.Revoker=true,hf.IntermediateCA=true' --id.secret icapw --tls.certfiles ${PWD}/organizations/fabric-ca/org1/tls-cert.pem
```

4. Run the Intermediate CA container as shown below with using the below config file.
5. Enrol the Intermediate CA

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://icaadmin:icaadminpw@localhost:6054 --caname ica-org1 --tls.certfiles ${PWD}/organizations/fabric-ca/icaOrg1/tls-cert.pem
```

Root CA

```
version: "2"

networks:
  test:

services:
  ca_org1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ../organizations/fabric-ca/org1:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    container_name: ca_org1
    networks:
      - test
```

Intermidate CA

```
version: "2"

networks:
  test:

services:
  ica-org1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ica-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=debug
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=6054
    ports:
      - "6054:6054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start  -b icaadmin:icaadminpw -u -d http://ica:icapw@ca-org1:7054'
    volumes:
      - ../organizations/fabric-ca/icaOrg1:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    container_name: ica-org1
    networks:
     - test
```

ICA Fabric Config file

```
# Version of config file
version: 1.2.0

# Server's listening port (default: 7054)
port: 7054

# Enables debug logging (default: false)
debug: false

# Size limit of an acceptable CRL in bytes (default: 512000)
crlsizelimit: 512000

tls:
  # Enable TLS (default: false)
  enabled: true
  # TLS for the server's listening port
  certfile:
  keyfile:
  clientauth:
    type: noclientcert
    certfiles:

ca:
  # Name of this CA
  name: ica.org1.example.com
  # Key file (is only used to import a private key into BCCSP)
  keyfile:
  # Certificate file (default: ca-cert.pem)
  certfile:
  # Chain file
  chainfile:

crl:
  # Specifies expiration for the generated CRL. The number of hours
  # specified by this property is added to the UTC time, the resulting time
  # is used to set the 'Next Update' date of the CRL.
  expiry: 24h


registry:
  # Maximum number of times a password/secret can be reused for enrollment
  # (default: -1, which means there is no limit)
  maxenrollments: -1

  # Contains identity information which is used when LDAP is disabled
  identities:
    - name: icaadmin
      pass: icaadminpw
      type: client
      affiliation: ""
      attrs:
        hf.Registrar.Roles: "client,peer,user,member"
        hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles: "client,peer,user,member"
        hf.Revoker: true
        hf.IntermediateCA: true
        hf.GenCRL: true
        hf.Registrar.Attributes: "*"
        hf.AffiliationMgr: true


db:
  type: sqlite3
  datasource: fabric-ca-server.db
  tls:
    enabled: false
    certfiles:
    client:
      certfile:
      keyfile:

ldap:
  # Enables or disables the LDAP client (default: false)
  # If this is set to true, the "registry" section is ignored.
  enabled: false
  # The URL of the LDAP server
  url: ldap://<adminDN>:<adminPassword>@<host>:<port>/<base>
  # TLS configuration for the client connection to the LDAP server
  tls:
    certfiles:
    client:
      certfile:
      keyfile:
  # Attribute related configuration for mapping from LDAP entries to Fabric CA attributes
  attribute:

    names: ["uid", "member"]
    converters:
      - name:
        value:
    maps:
      groups:
        - name:
          value:

affiliations:
  org1:
    - department1
    - department2

signing:
  default:
    usage:
      - digital signature
    expiry: 8760h
  profiles:
    ca:
      usage:
        - cert sign
        - crl sign
      expiry: 43800h
      caconstraint:
        isca: true
        maxpathlen: 0
    tls:
      usage:
        - signing
        - key encipherment
        - server auth
        - client auth
        - key agreement
      expiry: 8760h

csr:
  cn: ica.org1.example.com
  names:
    - C: US
      ST: "North Carolina"
      L: "Durham"
      O: org1.example.com
      OU:
  hosts:
    - localhost
    - org1.example.com
  ca:
    expiry: 131400h
    pathlength: 1

#############################################################################
# BCCSP (BlockChain Crypto Service Provider) section is used to select which
# crypto library implementation to use
#############################################################################
bccsp:
  default: SW
  sw:
    hash: SHA2
    security: 256
    filekeystore:
      # The directory used for the software file-based keystore
      keystore: msp/keystore


cacount:
cafiles:

intermediate:
  parentserver:
    url: https://ca-org1:7054
    caname: ca.org1.example.com

  enrollment:
    hosts: localhost
    profile:
    label:

  tls:
    certfiles:
    client:
      certfile:
      keyfile:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you configured your CAs as **TLS** enabled, root TLS certificate must be used by  intermediate CA. Check your intermediate CA file's corresponding section.

The **certfiles** attribute's value `/tmp/root-ca-cert.pem` is the same file of root CA's file: `/tmp/hyperledger/fabric-ca/crypto/ca-cert.pem`

```
intermediate:   
  parentserver:
    url: https://admin:admin@root.ca.example.com:7054
    caname: root.ca.example.com

  enrollment:
    hosts:
      - ca1.example.com
    profile: ca
    label:

  tls:
    certfiles:
      - /tmp/root-ca-cert.pem
    client:
      certfile:
      keyfile:
```

Comment: Thank you for replay, I have query in ```intermediate:   
  parentserver: url:https://admin:admin@root.ca.example.com:7054``` which admin is this

Comment: This is enrollment user of intermediate CA. In your case, it'd be `ica:icapwd`. If you use this configuration, you don't need to specify enrollment url in run command.

Comment: thank you. In tls certifies  section why it is root-ca-cert.pem ```/tmp/root-ca-cert.pem``` can we use ```tls-cert.pem``` from the root ca. Do I need to copy that file to container from the root ca ?

Comment: Yes, you need to copy that file from root CA. In order to establish a secure connection,  client (your intermediate CA) has to trust the server's identity. On TLS handshake with client & server, server sends its public key to client. Client is checking the signature in the public key, however client can't be sure if this signature is trustworthy. We're passing client the `root-ca-cert.pem` to say "_hey you can trust signatures signed with this certificate_" , so client finally trusts the server it's about to communicate.

Comment: I have question, when running the docker-compose for ROOTCA  when bootstrapping it also create ca.cert.pem file. Next i ll enroll ROOTCA admin that also generate ca-cert.pem folder inside ca-cert.pem which ca-cert.pem i need to  copy to intermidiate

Comment: when I start the docker-compose.yaml for intermediate with command ```sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start  -b icaadmin:icaadminpw``` its overriding my tls file.